# Swift Framework not building on Simulator but builds successfully on Physical device

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a framework for my clients.

1. I archive the framework and distribute it through cocoa pods.
2. When clients install the framework and try to build it on simulator
   they get compilation error i.e Use of unresolved identifier.
3. But the same code build on Physical device successfully. I assume it has something to do with architectures

Valid architectures is set to arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s x86_64 i386

Build active architecture is set to No for release.

This is the run script I use in archive post-actions.

```
exec > /tmp/${PROJECT_NAME}_archive.log 2>&1

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: Detected, stopping"
else
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

echo "Building for iPhoneSimulator"
xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE_PATH}" -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS='i386   x86_64' BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode clean build

# Step 1. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
echo "Copying to output folder"
cp -R "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 2. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/${TARGET_NAME}.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/${TARGET_NAME}.swiftmodule"
fi

# Step 3. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
echo "Combining executables"
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}"

# Step 4. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
echo "Copying to project dir"
yes | cp -Rf "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

open "${PROJECT_DIR}"

fi
```

Comment: So, what's the error? If you try to build it without this script, what happens? Are you trying to actually archive something? If so, why against a simulator? How about dependancies, any? In other words, can you provide enough details so we can duplicate your issue?

Comment: I've created a framework for my clients.
1. I archive the framework and distribute it through cocoapods.
2. When clients install the framework and try to build it on simulator they get compilation error i.e Use of unresolved identifiers.
3. But the same code build on Physical device successfully.

I assume it has something to do with architectures.

Comment: The framework itself has two dependencies: MessageKit and SocketIOClient

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't use third-party frameworks in my code (and never have created one) but this info seems (to me) to be important enough to belong in your question. One last thing you probably should include, since ABI compatibility is only with Swift 5. What version of Swift is your framework? Last thought - SocketIOClient... sounds like it uses things that may not work in a simulator. (Think Metal or using the Camera app.) Are you *sure* a simulator can run your framework?

Comment: Framework swift version is 4.2 and I'm sure that SocketIOClient will work on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script,

```
# Merge Script

# 1
# Set bash script to exit immediately if any commands fail.
set -e

# 2
# Setup some constants for use later on.
FRAMEWORK_NAME="<YOUR-FRAMEWORK-NAME>"

# 3
# If remnants from a previous build exist, delete them.
if [ -d "${SRCROOT}/build" ]; then
rm -rf "${SRCROOT}/build"
fi

# 4
# Build the framework for device and for simulator (using
# all needed architectures).
xcodebuild -target "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration Release -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphoneos"
xcodebuild -target "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration Release -arch x86_64 -arch i386 only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphonesimulator"

# 5
# Remove .framework file if exists on Desktop from previous run.
if [ -d "${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" ]; then
rm -rf "${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
fi

# 6
# Copy the device version of framework to Desktop.
cp -r "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" "${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

# 7
# Replace the framework executable within the framework with
# a new version created by merging the device and simulator
# frameworks' executables with lipo.
lipo -create -output "${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# 8
# Copy the Swift module mappings for the simulator into the
# framework.  The device mappings already exist from step 6.
#cp -r "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" "${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule"

# 9
# Delete the most recent build.
if [ -d "${SRCROOT}/build" ]; then
rm -rf "${SRCROOT}/build"
fi
```